# Empty div when clicked an image appears

Tags: html, css

I have searched the forums and cant really find something exactly for what i need, though there are similar things. I am in no way familiar with jquery, so would rather avoid that if at all possible. I can do HTML and CSS though.

I have a webpage i am designing that contains several containers. The overall parent container has an image, and then i will have empty divs within that container.

I want to make each div like a check box, so when it is clicked an image of a checkmark will appear.

how do i get this empty div to display an image only when it is clicked? my site is not launched yet and is still in design so i cant link to it. If any more info is needed please let me know. my html looks like this:

```
<div id= "parent container">
<img src="background image">
<div id="container1> i want this to be an empty div that when clicked shows an image</div>
<div id="container2> i want this to be an empty div that when clicked shows an image</div>
</div>
```

css looks something like this:

```
parent container { width:100%; display:block; margin: 0 auto;}
container1 {width:20%; display:block; top:10%; left:60%; height:20%;}
etc
```

basically i am trying to design my webpage to look like a cartoonized application (the background image is the application base). i want the user to be able to click the check boxes for whatever applies to him, and when he clicks it a check image appears.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need javascript in some form.

Comment: You can use a checkbox with text-indent:-9999, then when the user hits the box, add a css selector :checked ~ .yourdiv and the background for your div is a checkbox when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I suppose it could be done in CSS taking advantage of the same things you'd use for <a> tags (for menus and stuff).  But why would you go through any extra trouble when JS is right there for you to use?

Comment: http://codepen.io/designsbycamaron/pen/LBwCF

Comment: There is multiple ways of achieving what you want. The purpose of using CSS "IMO" is that all browsers support it. Each in its own different way of course. But there is no pondering if the person who is on your website has never upgraded there browser.. And even in that instance CSS can be problematic.  So yes I agree, jQuery / Javascript, can be a good use for this, but if you are a CSS wizard/warlok (we are evil for some reason IDK y) go for it.